Can't remove the initial instance and also animate it pass 1 full cycle!


Hello! I'm new to using geometry nodes and trying to animate a point which follows the circular curve but it seems to only go round once, and not in a loop. It also makes a duplicate which is left at the initial point of the curve. It would be a pleasure if someone could help me find my mistake and properly explain how to better use the nodes. Thanks!

Currently you are joining the outputs of the Instance on Points and the Set Position together with the final Join Geometry node.
The output of the Instance on Points is the 'duplicate' that is left behind.

